# Data relationship problem

Tags: c#, class-design

i have a problem in my class-design.

Ich have 2 classes:

```
public class A {
    public B[] _bs;
    public string _name;
}
public class B {
    public string getAName() {
        // The problem
    }
}
```

In words: I have two classes A and B.
The class A has many B's and a B has only one A!

Thats easy. But now i need a attribute from A through a method of B.

Sure I can create something like

```
public class B {
    public A _parent;
    public string getAName() {
        return _parent._name;
    }
}
```

But this, i think, is no good design...

My programming language is C# but this is a general problem..

What other possibilities can I use?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is the normal way to do it. I can't even think of another possible way to do it without doing something ridiculous like decompiling the dll. Possibly keeping a list of A's and having the B find which A it's in, but still very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you don't want to expose the entire `A` for your `B`?

```
public class B
{
    public A A {get;set;}
}
```

So instead of:

```
var aName = b.getAName();
```

... you'd say:

```
var aName = b.A.Name;
```

(In my world, you made a public `Name` property and made the `_name` field private.)

But speaking generally, it sounds like your concern is with having `A` point to `B` and `B` point to `A` at the same time. This is standard practice when representing bi-directional relationships like the one you're talking about. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I would probably recommend making the setter private and leaving the getter public.

Comment: @pstrjds: That may be appropriate, depending on what we're doing. It may even be better to have the setter add/remove `this` from the `_bs` list in the referenced `A`, so that it's actually changing both sides of the relationship. This is the way it is done in things like the Entity Framework.

Comment: Sure, that would be good too. I was just thinking of the danger of getting out of sync if the setter for A was exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Have the method belong to A, and have A invoke a method of B (possibly passing A's information to B as a parameter). You're correct in thinking it's a questionable design decision to have B responsible for distributing/processing A's information.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- If the property is fixed, it can be parameter to B constructor so B still doesnt know about A
- A implement an interface and the interface expose specific property(ies) only and B have reference to that. You can simply pass that it, set it or get fancy and use dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A 
{
    public List<B> _listOfB;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<B> ListOfB 
    {
        get { return _listOfB; }
    }

    public A() 
    {
        ListOfB = new List<B>();
    }

    public void AddB(B b) 
    {
        B.InstanceOfA = this;
        ListOfB.Add(b);
    }



}

public class B 
{
    public A InstanceOfA { get; set; }
}
```

Add a B's to A:

```
A a = new A();
a.Name = "AAAA";
A.AddB(new B());
A.AddB(new B());
A.AddB(new B());
```

The this:

```
foreach(B b in A.ListOfB)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b.InstanceOfA.Name);
}
```

Would result in:

```
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
```

But as always there is ofcourse there is more than one "good" solution :)
(for instance you could add a constructor to B where you pass a reference to A)

(Take care that you use AddB() and not ListOfB.Add(), otherwise InstanceOfA is not set (and ofcourse you can set it yourself and add it to ListOfB anyway)

Hope this helps.